# Are there any progressing development to solve debug/release differentiation within Task Runner Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, task-runner-explorer

The last post I've found about this topic is from autumn 2015. I think this is one of those basic things every developer will need sooner or later.

I would like to differentiate my gulp tasks based on actual build configuration (debug/staging/release) etc. I don't actually need to connect it with Visual Studio's solution configuration.

Here is a proposed solution: we would have this as an option inside Task Runner Explorer, and then at task binding I could tick in in which configurations I would like to run the task.

Is it only me who would need this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use TRX but you can bind any of these tasks to an event like "Project Open" or "Before Build." I use gulp-if and set variables in my parent task, then call all child tasks with `run-sequence`. (untested code)

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
       $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
       requireDir = require('require-dir')('./js/gulp/tasks'),
       runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
       vars = require('./variables');

gulp.task('dev', function(){
      vars.isProduction = false;
      runSequence('clean', ['css', 'scripts']);
});
gulp.task('prod', function(){
      vars.isProduction = true;
      runSequence('clean', ['css', 'scripts']);
});
```

**/js/gulp/tasks/scripts.js**

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
       .pipe($.concat('app.min.js'))
       .pipe($.if(vars.isProduction, $.uglify()))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('/js'))
       .pipe($.plumber({
          errorHandler: vars.onError
        }))
       .pipe($.if(!vars.isProduction, $.livereload()));
```

**variables.js**

```
module.exports = {
    isProduction: false,
    onError: function (err) {
        log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: THank you for your answer. I don't yet understand how you would bind the `dev` and `prod` tasks separately in TRX AfterBuild (for example). You still need some setting about which one to use, or maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your OP about not needing it to bind to Visual Studio's solution configuration. My dev tasks are usually just gulp watchers though, and I run those in a [separate command window](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e84e2cf-2d6b-472a-b1e2-b84932511379). If you're using a build server you can run the prod tasks as part of the build definition